# How do I add the "View Website" action to a timeline card?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

As of firmware update XE7, Glass adds a "View Website" action to search results.  How do I add this action to my own timeline cards, such that it will open the Glass Browser with an arbitrary URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `OPEN_URI` built-in menu item to your timeline item and the URL to `menuItem.payload`. The JSON for a timeline item might look like this:

```
{ 
  "text" : "Hello World!",
  "menuItems" : [{
    "action" : "OPEN_URI",
    "payload" : "http://example.com"
  }]
}
```

You can read more about built-in menu items on the [official documentation for this feature](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#menuItems.action).

Comment: Thanks, Jenny. [Issue 137: Make "View Website" a built-in menu action](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=137)

Comment: Well, it's documented as part of https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert under menuItems[].action = VIEW_WEBSITE so does XE7 not support handling those?